# How to install MySQL-python with custom python and custom mysql

Tags: python, linux

I don't have root permission and this centos does not have network.

Well, I'm gonna connect mysql with python and the system python doesn't have MySQLdb.

So I have to install my own python under my home.

I install stuffs under **usr** directory except for **mysql** which is installed by system administrtor. It is something like this:

```
~
└── usr
    ├── bin
    ├── include
    ├── lib
    ├── mysql
    └── share
```

After I installed MySQL-python, and **import MySQLdb**, it tells me:

```
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 31 2015, 22:04:52)
[GCC 3.4.5 20051201 (Red Hat 3.4.5-2)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import MySQLdb
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 19, in <module>
    import _mysql
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 7, in <module>
  File "build/bdist.linux-x86_64/egg/_mysql.py", line 6, in __bootstrap__
ImportError: libmysqlclient_r.so.16: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

YES, I definitely did this:

```
ln -s ~/usr/mysql/lib/mysql/libmysqlclient_r.so.16 ~/usr/lib/
```

I'm stuck here. Anyone can help me out? thx

Comment: You meant you did this, right? `ln -s ~/usr/lib/libmysqlclient.so.16 path/to/mysql/lib/libmysqlclient_r.so.16`

Comment: @agold yes! It's a common step to install mysql-python, but this time it doesn't help.

Comment: Yes I know, I commented it since in your question the `ln -s` command contains the '_r' file name twice!

Comment: @agold Oh, sorry, there is something wrong about the `ln -s` and I edited the question

Answer (score 0):

Well, I finally worked out.

I've missed this:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=~/usr/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```